# CSV file content is appearing in one row?

Tags: javascript, csv

I have downloaded CSV file from server i.e. http response body and using Blob I am opening it.
But the problem is CSV File content is appearing in one row, we have maintained `\r\n` as row separator.

[image]

CSV in http response
[image]

output file
[image]

in coumn N you can see `\r\n` which we have used as a separator.
I tried searching through lot of blogs but didn't get a break.

Comment: Can you try with \\r\\n ?

Comment: Hi Lajos, It didn't work.

Comment: Hi,

Sorry for the delayed Response.
Actually in back end while converting an ABAP internal table to CSV we have to add "Carriage Return and Line Feed" Character.
CONCATENATE lv_string cl_abap_char_utilities=>cr_lf INTO lv_string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed Response. Actually in back end while converting an ABAP internal table to CSV we have to add "Carriage Return and Line Feed" Character.

CONCATENATE lv_string cl_abap_char_utilities=>cr_lf INTO lv_string.

[image]

Thanks,
Abhi